# Get table column name, data type and column alias name in materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I get the column name of the physical table, data type of the column and the alias name that the materialized view has

similar to this detail.

TABLE:orders

DATA->VARCHAR

DATA2->NUMBER

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW order_data REFRESH COMPLETE 
   AS 
SELECT DATA AS EXAMPLE1,
 DATA2 AS EXAMPLE2
  FROM orders;
```

Desired result:

```
VIEW NAME  | NAME COLUMN | TYPE OF DATE | COLUMN ALIASES
order_data | DATA        | VARCHAR      | EXAMPLE1
order_data | DATA2       | NUMBER       | EXAMPLE2
```

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, specifically the part about "column name". In general, the `SELECT` clause of a query (in particular of the query defining a view, including a materialized one) can be any kind of expression, not a simple copy of a column from a base table. The column in the materialized view can be `t.sal + t.com` (salary plus commission, from two different columns in table `t`) - what do you want your result to be then? What if the view column is defined through a function? What if it's a constant like 'APPROVED' (same value in every row)?

Comment: What if the input is a single column in a single table - holding JSON documents? The view extracts the data and presents it in eight different columns, of different data types. Do you want your result to show the same "column name" (from the underlying table) for all the view columns? BETTER QUESTION (for you) - WHY do you need this? The problem seems very unnatural. You have access to the view definition, why can't you inspect it? Do you want to write your own parser, to replace the one Oracle wrote?